# How to make checkbox check toggle between two checkbox groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am creating two groups of checkbox having same values in it. One is a list of fruits to accept and another is a list of fruits to reject.

Both checkbox list is having same fruit names and values.

Now I need to make sure that user selecting fruits from the first group, should not select the fruit name from the second group and vice-versa.

I tried something like this.

```
$('input[name="acceptFruit"]').click(function(){
        let acceptedFruits = $(this).val();
        $('input:checkbox[name="rejectFruit"][value="' + acceptedFruits + '"]').attr('checked', false);
    });
```

Please suggest me how to proceed using Jquery.

Comment: checkbox or radio buttons ?

Comment: It is a list of checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `change` event on all your checkboxes, then if your checkbox just got checked, uncheck every other checkbox with the same value :

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('input[name^="list"][value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'"]').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="first">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list1" value="1"/> 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list1" value="2"/> 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list1" value="3"/> 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="second">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list2" value="1"/> 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list2" value="2"/> 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="list2" value="3"/> 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`input:checkbox` won't match anything.

Use only `input` or `input[type="checkbox"][name="rejectFruit"][value="..."]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xoL6mLn/1/) for you. Also, I have assumed in my solution that respective values of items in accept & reject list are same.

```js
var complements = {
 accept: 'reject',
  reject: 'accept'
};

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
  var type = complements[$(this).prop('name')];
  
  $(`input[name=${type}][value=${val}]`).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Accept:
<input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="1"> Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="2"> Banana
<input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="3"> Orange

<br>
Reject:
<input type="checkbox" name="reject" value="1"> Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="reject" value="2"> Banana
<input type="checkbox" name="reject" value="3"> Orange
```

Hope that helps :)